# MarkLogic to hadoop replication

Tags: marklogic

Can we have MarkLogic to Hadoop replication using the connector?

I am trying to set up MarkLogic and we wanted to set up replication. 
So any new updates in MarkLogic, we need to update the records on Hadoop file system

Comment: This isn't really the use case for the connector.  It's intended to push key value pairs for MapReduce functions, and/or retrieving the data after processing. https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/input

Comment: Can i setup marklogic on Hadoop infrastructure ?

Comment: New questions deserve a separate SO page, but I think the answer is simply yes. See http://www.marklogic.com/what-is-marklogic/marklogic-hadoop/marklogic-on-hdfs/